# Cancatinate string for -exec command in find

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a simple script that gathers user input and then assembles a find command line to process a bunch of files. I've tried several variables to replace within the string to no avail.

Here's the code:

```
PRESET="High Profile"
X264TUNE="Film"

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
    TRANSCODEDIR="."
else
    TRANSCODEDIR="$1"
fi
find "$TRANSCODEDIR"/* -type f -exec bash -c '/usr/bin/HandBrakeCLI -i "$1" -o "${1%\.*}".mp4 -x264-preset="$PRESET" x264-tune="$X264TUNE" --encoder="x264"' __ {} \;
```

I can't seem to get the variable replacements to work in the executed find command. I've tried combinations of single and doubles quotes to no avail.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That looks correct. Try `bash -x -c '...'` to see what extra tracing shows.

Comment: The `bash` process running under `find` isn't inheriting the variables in the script. You'll either need to export the variables (`export FOO=bar` instead of just `FOO=bar`) or pass them directly to the `find` command. (`FOO=bar find ...`)

Comment: Thanks @iscfrc. That's it. The variables obviously aren't available in the scope in which the find command is executing. Exporting them worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Another approach is to use a `while read` loop and do all the processing inside the loop and avoid the `export` part, not that it matters so much.